# Incessant screen flickering on Ubuntu 16.10, Macbook Pro 11,5

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.10, macbook, flicker

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 and the screen is flickering as if a graphics driver update is needed, and some elements may not display, like chrome extensions such as Checker Plus for Gmail. but I am on the latest updates as far as I am aware. Are there any specific graphic updates for the macbook pro 11,5 that I should be looking for?

Thanks

EDIT: I have at least stabilized things for now by de-selecting the option 
[pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xe87.png)

and setting the display resolution to 1920x1080 from previously 
2880x1800.

EDT 2: Here is the output from `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus
XT [Radeon HD 8870M / R9 M270X/M370X] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Radeon R9 M370X Mac Edition
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

If I left out any other useful info please let me know, I am new to using Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I have added the edit you requested, @Pilot6

Comment: The microcode option is not related, but the resolution could help.